# Naïve Prime Factorization in Clojure Pt. 2

Tags: primes, clojure, factors

After my last [review request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209706/na%C3%AFve-prime-factorization-in-clojure), I decided to try and make a "tree" visualization, and thought that I could benefit from making `find-prime-factors` lazily produce prime factors so the visualization can be updated in real time as factors are found.

This is what I ended up with. I was actually surprised how easy it was to adapt the `loop` to a recursive `lazy-seq` solution. The non-return accumulators were added as parameters to a recursive function, and the lazy return list was created via the typical `(lazy-seq (cons ... ...))`. It actually performs identically to the previous strict version too when evaluation is forced using `vec`.

If anyone sees anything here that can be commented on, I'd like to know.

---

```
(doseq [p (lazily-find-prime-factors 99930610001)]
  (println p 
           (int (/ (System/currentTimeMillis) 1000))))
163 1544998649
191 1544998692
3209797 1544998692
```

---

Same as in the last review:

```
(ns irrelevant.prime-factorization.prime-factorization)

(defn is-factor-of? [n multiple]
  (zero? (rem n multiple)))

(defn prime? [n]
  (or (= n 2) ; TODO: Eww
      (->> (range 2 (inc (Math/sqrt ^double n)))
           (some #(is-factor-of? n %))
           (not))))

(defn primes []
  (->> (range)
       (drop 2) ; Lower bound of 2 for the range
       (filter prime?)))

(defn smallest-factor-of? [n possible-multiples]
  (some #(when (is-factor-of? n %) %)
        possible-multiples))
```

---

Updated:

```
(defn lazily-find-prime-factors [n]
  (letfn [(rec [remaining remaining-primes]
            (when-let [small-prime (and (> remaining 1)
                                        (smallest-factor-of? remaining remaining-primes))]
              (lazy-seq
                (cons small-prime
                      (rec (long (/ remaining small-prime))
                           (drop-while #(not= % small-prime) remaining-primes))))))]
    (rec n (primes))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that the `lazily-find-prime-factors` function needs is the `(primes)` sequence. You just keep trying each in turn. Your `smallest-factor-of` drops the failed factors, but forgets what it has done, so you have to do it again for the recursive call.

And I'd rename your `is-factor-of?` function:

```
=> (is-factor-of? 4 2)
true
=> (is-factor-of? 2 4)
false
```

... reads wrongly. I've called it `divides-by?`.

I end up with ...

```
(defn lazily-find-prime-factors [n]
  (letfn [(rec [remaining remaining-primes]
            (when (> remaining 1)
              (let [rp (drop-while #(not (divides-by? remaining %)) remaining-primes)
                    small-prime (first rp)]
                (lazy-seq (cons small-prime
                            (rec (quot remaining small-prime) rp))))))]
   (rec n (primes))))
```

Factoring the problem this way, you can easily plug in an efficient way of generating primes.